# Express - Authenticating app's request to API

Tags: javascript, angular, express

I'm trying to build an application using Angular 5 (for the client), Express (for the server) and MySQL.
There's a point in the app where I want to make an http request to the server in order to fetch some product data to use it in the app. I have a service with the following line of code:

```
this.http.get('http://localhost/api/?products=all')
```

This request returns all the products available in the database. Now how can I make sure that this request is sent from the app (in this case from that service)?
If I try http://localhost/api/?products=all for example in the browser all the data will be returned and obviously it is not wanted. So how can I authenticate these requests to the api?
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You can use middleware function to authenticate request

```
function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
      // do any checks you want to in here

      // CHECK THE USER STORED IN SESSION FOR A CUSTOM VARIABLE
      // you can do this however you want with whatever variables you set up
      if (req.user.authenticated)
          return next();

      // IF A USER ISN'T LOGGED IN, THEN REDIRECT THEM SOMEWHERE
      res.redirect('/');
    }
```